# I cannot change the Gutter color on RSyntaxTextArea library

Tags: java, swing, colors, gutter, rsyntaxtextarea

Good afternoon everyone, I am not extremely experienced in coding, after long experimentation with RSyntaxTextArea I am still unable to change the Gutter. I cannot figure out how to code the Gutter Color, I would like to change the Gutter color to this new Color(9, 11, 16);
Can someone please try to help me figure this out?

This is the library **https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea**

[This is my editor and the Gutter kinda ruins the vibe when I am changing themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFAsi.png)

Comment: Have you tried `sp.getGutter().setBackground(new Color(9, 11, 16));`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, editing a xml file is not that hard.

```
public void changeStyleViaThemeXml(RSyntaxTextArea textArea, String path) {
    try {
        Theme theme = Theme.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        theme.apply(textArea);
    } catch (IOException ioe) { // Never happens
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```